# substitute complex text string in several files that contains special characters

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I need to replace a complex string in several files in a directory.

The string that needs replaced is:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

With: `./logo.jpg`

I'm having all kinds of issues using sed for the replacement due to the various special characters in the string that needs replaced.

Comment: For the given string, you could use `sed` with another delimiter: `sed 's|yourstringgoeshere|./logo.jpg|'`.

Comment: There aren't really any special characters in that string. As sed supports nearly any character as delimiter, you only need to pick something that is not contained in the string you search for or that you want to replace it with.

In your case, probably | or _ should work, just tested.
For more details see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 0):

How about a regular expression:

```
sed -r -i 's/(data:image\/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQoAAAAkCAAAAABUcSvnAAAHbklEQVRo3u2Ya0xURxTHR9Yt6CJdLSU0hFoxPhIS41ujDex).*(HHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)/.\/logo.jpg/g' filename
```

Look for the beginning and the end of the string and replace with `.\/logo.jpg` in `filename`.

Use `-i` to replace the content in the filename.

Comment: Nope.. doesn't seem to work.